# Summarizing data-frame with NA

Tags: r

I have 3 different class of mutation such as

```
 "CNA"                "MUTATIONS"          "STRUCTURAL_VARIANT"


f <- dput(e)
structure(list(track_name = c("AR", "ASCL1", "ATOH1", "PRDM1", 
"DLX1", "DLX2", "EPAS1", "ETV2", "EYA2", "FOXG1", "FOXC2", "GATA1", 
"GATA2", "GATA3", "GATA4", "GATA6", "GBX1", "GLI2", "GLI3", "MNX1"
), track_type = c("CNA", "CNA", "CNA", "CNA", "CNA", "CNA", "CNA", 
"CNA", "CNA", "CNA", "CNA", "CNA", "CNA", "CNA", "CNA", "CNA", 
"CNA", "CNA", "CNA", "CNA"), `TCGA-AB-2929` = c("amp_rec", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Amplification", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), aml_ohsu_2018_1408 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    aml_ohsu_2018_1992 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This gives me data-frame as such

```
track_name track_type `TCGA-AB-2929` aml_ohsu_2018_1408 aml_ohsu_2018_1992
   <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <chr>              <chr>             
 1 AR         CNA        amp_rec        NA                 NA                
 2 ASCL1      CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
 3 ATOH1      CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
 4 PRDM1      CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
 5 DLX1       CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
 6 DLX2       CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
 7 EPAS1      CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
 8 ETV2       CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
 9 EYA2       CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
10 FOXG1      CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
11 FOXC2      CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
12 GATA1      CNA        Amplification  NA                 NA                
13 GATA2      CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
14 GATA3      CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
15 GATA4      CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
16 GATA6      CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
17 GBX1       CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
18 GLI2       CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
19 GLI3       CNA        NA             NA                 NA                
20 MNX1       CNA        NA             NA                 NA
```

This is of my small subset. For each sample there are first column contains gene and the second column contain the mutation class.

I m trying to find the mutation distribution of each gene in those class across the samples. My column after the second column contains various mutation such as

Amplification,Inframe Mutation (putative passenger),Deep Deletion,Missense Mutation (putative passenger) which are distributed across each column of the samples.

In my example data-frame I have one such observation

```
GATA1 CNA Amplification
```

Im doing this

```
table(Store2df$track_name, Store2df$track_type) %>% prop.table() %>% round(2)
```

Is there in better method/ways to summaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily a better way but if you are using `dplyr` you can do this -

```
library(dplyr)

e %>%
  count(track_name, track_type) %>%
  mutate(n = round(prop.table(n), 2))
```

This will return data in long format.

Comment: if I have to summaries in terms of column information which starts after 2nd column ? for example I have these in my various column Amplification,Inframe Mutation (putative passenger),Deep Deletion,Missense Mutation (putative passenger) is it possible to do that way?

Comment: Hmmm..I am not sure if I have understood you completely but you may want to get the data in long format and perform the count.